# SUM of two level group by in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have three table as given below

**student**

```
id  name    stand_id    sub_id  gender
---------------------------------------
1 | Joe  |  1       |      1     |     M
2 | Saun |  2       |      1     |     F
3 | Paul |  1       |      2     |     F
4 | Sena |  2       |      2     |     M
```

**Subject**

```
id  name            
1   Math            
2   English
```

**Standard**

```
id  name            
1   First           
2   Second
```

How can I achieve this kind of multiple group by like standard, subject than total number of boys and girls.

Should I use with, union or union all ?

```
First
Math 
boys       total
girls      total

second
math
boys       total
girls      total
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you are attempting. My interpretation is that you are looking for the total of students by `standard`, `subject` and `gender`.

If that is correct, you need to join together the tables and count the students at the appropriate grain, like so:

```
SELECT
    sta.name AS standard_name,
    sub.name AS subject_name,
    CASE stu.gender WHEN 'M' THEN 'Boys' ELSE 'Girls' END AS student_gender,
    COUNT(stu.id) AS total
FROM
    student stu
JOIN
    subject sub
    ON  (stu.sub_id = sub.id)
JOIN
    standard sta
    ON  (stu.stand_id = sta.id)
GROUP BY
    standard_name,
    subject_name,
    student_gender;
```

Based on your sample data, it would return this:

```
standard_name | subject_name | student_gender | total
-----------------------------------------------------
 First        | Math         | Boys           | 1
 First        | English      | Girls          | 1
 Second       | Math         | Girls          | 1
 Second       | English      | Boys           | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for

```
SELECT sd.name,
       sj.name,
       count(st.gender) filter (
                                WHERE st.gender='M') AS MALE,
       count(st.gender) filter (
                                WHERE st.gender='F') AS FEMALE
FROM Standard sd
INNER JOIN Student st ON (st.stand_id=sd.id)
INNER JOIN Subject sj ON (sj.id=st.sub_id)
GROUP BY sd.name,
         sj.name;

  name  |  name   | male | female
--------+---------+------+--------
 First  | Math    |    1 |      0
 First  | English |    0 |      1
 Second | English |    2 |      1
 Second | Math    |    0 |      1
(4 rows)
```

I have added some more rows to second English.